# How to join the n element in list 1 with the n element in list 2 and so on

Tags: python

i have two python lists, one containing words and the other containing numbers, i want to be able to join list1[0] with list2[0] and so on and put the results into a new list, using something like the following:

```
list1= [1,2,3,4]
list2=["nest","middle","crow""damage"]
```

i tried asking an ai and it returned the following code that gets close enough but it doesnt necesarily does what i want it to do i think:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = ["nest", "middle", "crow", "damage"]

list3 = [f"{i}{j}" for i, j in enumerate(list2)]

print(list3)
```

i want list3 to be something like the following:

list3=["nest1","midldle2","crow3","damage4"]

Comment: `zip()` is the usual way to join matching elements in two lists.

Answer (score 2):

Using `zip`:

```
[f"{i}{j}" for i, j in zip(list2, list1)]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = ["nest", "middle", "crow", "damage"]

list3 = [list2[i] + str((list1[i])) for i in range(len(list1))]

print(list3) #output : ['nest1', 'middle2', 'crow3', 'damage4']

#The above one-liner is equivalent to the following:
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = ["nest", "middle", "crow", "damage"]
list3 = []

for i in range(len(list1)):
    value = list2[i] + str(list1[i])
    list3.append(value)

print(list3) #output : ['nest1', 'middle2', 'crow3', 'damage4']
```

Comment: Using `zip()` is a much better solution.

Comment: Yes, true. My intention is to OP understand how the iteration works. I understandd that the OP has trouble understanding the iteration  seeing his question. He asked this even after getting a wrong answer from AI.

Comment: The zip answer is simpler, clearer, and shorter.